# How to map a value over a list of functions in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Disclaimer: I'm new to Mathematica

I know I can use Map to map a function over a list of data but is there a way to "Map" a value over a list of functions?

For example say I have 3 functions:

```
f2[x_]:=x^2
f3[x_]:=x^3
f4[x_]:=x^4

funcList={f2,f3,f4}
```

Now if I wanted to make a new list where I map a value over this list to create a new list? Like if I were to use the value two I would get:

```
MapValue[2,funcList]
{4,8,16}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html).

```
f2[x_] := x^2
f3[x_] := x^3
f4[x_] := x^4

funcList = {f2, f3, f4};

Through[funcList[2]]
```

> {4, 8, 16}

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function that calls another function:

```
call[g_] := g[2]

Map[call, funcList]

(* {4, 8, 16} *)
```

This can be simplified using the [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) syntax:

```
   #[2]& /@ funcList

(* ^~~~~ ^~ 
       |  short-form of Map
       |
       ~~ same as the `call` above 
 *)
```